# Why am I getting a different value when decrypting data than was encrypted?

Tags: encryption, rsa

In studying computer security this semester, we're currently reviewing cryptographic systems. I wanted to refresh myself on RSA, so went back over things from my discrete math book. But I think I've made a mistake.

For my plain text I'm using my first name:

```
Darryl = 68 01 18 18 25 12
```

For my primes I picked:

```
p=23 and q=11, so n=23*11=253.
```

The totient of n is:

```
(p-1)(q-1) = 22*10 = 220.
```

I chose `e=9` and `d=49` since `9*49=441` which is congruent with `1 mod 220`.

Encrypting each byte of my name I get:

```
68^9 mod 220 = 28
1^9 mod 220 = 1
18^9 mod 220 = 8
18^9 mod 220 = 8
25^9 mod 220 = 125
12^9 mod 220 = 12
```

But decrypting I'm getting:

```
28^49 mod 220 = 68
1^49 mod 220 = 1
8^49 mod 220 = 128  <--- these are wrong
8^49 mod 220 = 128
125^49 mod 220 = 25
12^49 mod 220 = 12
```

I'm not sure why decrypting the encrypted "r" is resulting in a different value. Any ideas?

Comment: Computing `d` happens modulo phi (220), encryption/decryption should happen modulo `n` (253) not modulo phi.

Comment: I think it's unavoidable that 1 will not be encrypted; i.e., since it's always c^e mod n where c=the byte the be encrypted, it will always encrypted 1 as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption is `x^e mod n`, and decryption `x^d mod n`. Your `n` is `253`, but you are using `220` instead.

That gives `18^9 mod 253 = 173`. Decrypting that gives `173^49 mod 253` which is `18`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize I wasn't using n but totient(n) instead. Thank you!